# Confused about OnSubmit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I have:

```
<form onSubmit= {handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="focusedInput">Level</label>
        <input className="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="number" />               
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn " type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

in my `handleSubmit`, how do I pass in the value in my form-control (type="number") into a props function? `event.target.value` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need the make the input a controlled input via state. You wouldn’t usually extract the input value from the form event object itself, but the component’s state. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use state for controlled input.

example:

```
this.state={
    number :0 //initialise state variable here or in componentWillMount or componentDidMount
}

handleChange(e){
// input change handler,extract value from e, update state here.
this.setState({
    number: e.target.value
})

handleSubmit(){
    // Use state variable and make ajax call or anything you want with your input here.
}
```

Your input form will look like this.

```
<input className="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="number" value={this.state.number} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)/> 
//you can bind your function in constructor too.
```

Your submit button will look like this

```
<button className="btn " onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)>Submit</button>
```

`bind(this)` is important, you need to bind your function in constructor or same as mentioned above. when you bind it in constructor, you don't need to write `bind(this)` in `input` and `button`

Answer (score 0):

There are few way to address it:

1. Save values into state onChange event. Good examples in docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.
2. Define `ref` and read value on submit. 
   https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html